# How the following relational expression written in if-else statement is understood by the C Compiler?

Tags: c, if-statement, operators

I am unable to understand why this code is displaying 20 30 40 as output. Can anyone explain how the relational expression written in if statement is understood by the C Compiler ?

[This is the image of code of the C Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FjfI.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int i = 20, j = 30, k = 40;
   if (i > j == k)
   {
       printf("%d %d %d ",--i,j++,++k);
   }
   else
   {
       printf("%d %d %d ",i,j,k );
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

`20 30 40`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) `i > j == k` is executed as `(i > j) == k`

So `i > j` is executed first, returning a boolean (here, `false`, ie `0`)
And result is compared to `k`, which is not equal to `0`. Condition is than false, so `else` part of condition is executed

Answer (score 2):

first thing to consider is operator precedence. the operator > is evaluated before the operator == and it returns a value. in this case, i > j is wrong so it returns zero. then it checks if zero equals to k which is 40 and it isn't. so it goes to else branch.